# String replace all sub string found matching the list of strings C# LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I have a string

```cs
originalString: "String must be replaced for all the occurrences found in the replace string"
```

I have a List

```cs
stringToRemovedList = {"to", "be", "in", "the", "for", "all"}
```

`originalString` should be removed with all the strings found in the `stringTobeRemoved` list.

Formatted string should be

```cs
"String must replaced occurrences found replace string"
```

What is the best LINQ query?

Comment: Is this homework? Can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldnt use linq to do this. But if you want you can do this in this way:

```
Regex trimmer = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
string[] s1 = new string[] { "bb", "dd" };
string s = "aa bb cc dd ee";
s1.ToList().ForEach(x => s = s.Replace(x,""));
s = trimmer.Replace(s, " ");
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What is the need for Regex here?

Comment: To ramove excess spaces.